# RewriteRule not writing at all in .htaccess for Windows (Apache)

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess

**Problem**

I´m using a [tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html) to learn to use Zend Framework. I can´t get past the "make sure .htaccess is working" part. I understand that there are PLENTY of questions about this for windows, and I will be mentioning what I have done so that we can be in the same page.

The content of .htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

In short, when I type url\fileDoesntExist , the .htaccess rules should catch and transform it to index.php . That´s all.

Here is the thing, it is not Rewriting the request AT ALL, giving me a 404 not found error, which I understand because it is looking for a "fileDoesntExist" (which, obviously doesn´t exist). When I look into the error logs of that virtualhost the Get post is GET /fileDoesntExist ...that is WRONG, since it should be GET /index.php because of the RewriteRule placed in .htaccess.

**Environment**

Windows 8
Apache 2.4

httpd.conf

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so  --> UNCOMMENTED
AccessFilename htaccess --> (some have said that for Windows, it should be placed without the 
                              leading dot)
<Directory "C:\Apache24\hosts\zf2-tutorial\public">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    Require all granted
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L] --> one user said that in windows if the rewriteRule is
                                            not placed here, then it won´t take place.
 </Directory>
```

**Ideas tried to no avail**

Through phpinfo(); I can see that the rewrite_module is in fact loaded. 
If I erase de content inside .htaccess and put something like this "aksdhfñashfña" (garbage) I DO get an "Internal Server Error".

I don´t know what could be the problem and help would be very much appreciated since it´s very frustrating  to spend time with configuration instead of developing.

Following De Morgan´s law I tried to tweak the content of .htaccess so that it will only care for when the requested page is not found.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

- Remove `AccessFilename` directive (`.htaccess` is used by default)
- Change your `<Directory>` to (remove all the clutter)

  ```
  <Directory "C:/Apache24/hosts/zf2-tutorial/public"> <!-- forward slashes -->
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny <!-- Fix your order (allow first) -->
      Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ```
- Make sure `.htaccess` is located at `DocumentRoot`

Comment: did all of those, same result. :S

Comment: I hop you did a restart too. Also check that you have `DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/hosts/zf2-tutorial/public"` configured as well.

Comment: I did a restart, got paranoid and even did a stop, waited five minutes then started again. And yes, I do have the DocumentRoot placement as suggested. I give up xD

Comment: Before you give up try downloading a Windows 7 (32-bit) Apache version and setup things up again on your D: drive now. (I'm using Apache 2.2 on a Windows 7 machine without any problems.) I know this isn't a solution but the problem I see is that you're not being able to start your learning and development project. Give it a shot mate. :)